# Choose between a high number of database calls or reduce the number of calls by aggregating information in a single search

Tags: sql-server, performance

In a large project with a volume of three hundred requests per second, we have a service that includes all customer information, including a table of identity information and another table of account information and postal information, etc., which includes ten tables. Delivery of the customer is given. The output volume of the data generated from Joven is 100k. It will cost less for our database or join our database Let's create a profile and give it to the client in the form of a service ?? While we provide each entity with each entity to call, for example, our profile service should be called ten separate services, but when we create the profile ourselves, it is called once, but it costs money. Join the tables on our database

Comment: It appears you forgot to ask a question. Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer website, you need to ask a question, so that we can answer you.

Comment: Model - test - evaluate - choose. Far too broad for SO.